# The "GetJavaPlatformJar" task was not given a value for the required parameter

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 15.7.4

Xamarin Forms, building for Android and using .NetStandard

**Error Messages:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(609,2): 
error MSB4044: The "GetJavaPlatformJar" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AndroidSdkPlatform".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(609,2): 
error MSB4044: The "GetJavaPlatformJar" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AndroidSdkDirectory".
```

**I have attempted:**

1. Cleaning and rebuilding
2. Deleting "bin" and "obj" and rebuilding
3. Reinstalling Visual Studio
4. Reinstalling the Android SDK
5. Changing Minimum Android Version, Target Android Version, and
   Compile Using Version
6. Adjusting my glasses and staring awkwardly for long periods of time

Any suggestions?

**[Build Output:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/de51vtz4z2npufz/BuildOutput.rtf?dl=0)**

Comment: Do you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that one can look into? It looks like it cannot find a proper `android.jar` for the version of Android you're targetting. Specifically the Android SDK on your local machine might not have everything it needs.

Comment: @Jon Douglas I can recreate the issue simply by creating a brand new Xamarin Forms project, and selecting .NETStandard instead of shared.
As long as you have the same Visual Studio version, you will get the same project as I get when following that flow. If you think it makes the question better, I can zip that and upload.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my comment after you posted one. This looks like the Android SDK might be misconfigured. I can build just fine following a new Xamarin.Forms project using .NETStandard on 15.7.4.

Comment: Can you include a [full diagnostic build output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#diagnostic-msbuild-output)?

Comment: I currently have multiple projects on the machine that build to Android just fine, the only difference being they are using PCL instead of .NETStandard. Is there a different requirement on the Android SDK side when using a different project type like that?

Comment: @JonDouglas Diagnostic build output added

Comment: No, there should not be. .NETStandard has been supported for almost 2 major releases.

Comment: From your build log, it shows `AndroidSdkPath: ` meaning that it's empty. To compare my working build, I might see `AndroidSdkPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`. This should be set via `ResolveSdks` task which is called by `_SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion` which your app is skipping: `2>Target "_SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion" skipped. Previously built successfully.` I think this would require an actual reproduction to see what's going on further. Also potentially a [binlog](http://msbuildlog.com/) / `msbuild MySolution.sln /bl` would generate and help us further debug.

Comment: I would consider this to be worthy of filing an issue since Stack Overflow isn't the best place. [Please file an issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/Submitting-Bugs,-Feature-Requests,-and-Pull-Requests#where-to-file-an-issue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174753/discussion-between-allen-and-jon-douglas).